# Qt C++ Drag QHeaderView between tables

Tags: c++, qt, draggable, qtableview, qtablewidget

I want to copy the selected column of a `QTableWidget` to another one.

So I tried to make selected columns draggable by adding this code:

```
void makeDraggable(QTableWidget *table)
{
    table->setDragEnabled(true);
    table->setAcceptDrops(true);
    table->setSelectionBehavior(QAbstractItemView::SelectColumns);
}
```

Result I got:

[image]

But I want to drag a whole column (horizontal and vertical headers) by clicking on headers only, not on cells, and copy its data to another table including the header text.

Comment: Let's assume that what you want works but that the number of rows of the qtableview are not the same, for example if the first had 3 rows and the second 100 then drag the column from the first tableview to the second and dropping it in the 15th row. Rows should those items be pasted? Or using your example if the mouse is released in the last row, where should the information be pasted?

Comment: Because we want to paste a whole column by dragging the header (not cells) we are able to insert data only to another QHeaderView of another table. If current rows < actual rows we just insert a part of data min(current, actual).

Could you provide an example how to drag QHeaderView between tables, please?

Comment: Ah, okay, now I understand you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dragging between different tables inside one application can be done with reimplementing custom `QHeaderView` and `QTableWidget`. In my example I generate text with indecies of table and column for drag event. **Custom header:**

```
#include <QHeaderView>

class ITableManager;

class DraggableHeaderView : public QHeaderView
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit DraggableHeaderView(Qt::Orientation orientation, QWidget *parent = 0);

    int tag() const;
    void setTag(const int tag);
    void setTableManager(ITableManager* manager);

protected:
    void mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *e);

    void dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event);
    void dragMoveEvent(QDragMoveEvent *event);
    void dropEvent(QDropEvent *event);

signals:

public slots:

private:
    int m_tag;  //internal index of table
    ITableManager *m_tableManager;  //manager will convert table index into pointer
};
```

**Custom header cpp**

```
#include <QMouseEvent>
#include <QDrag>
#include <QMimeData>
#include <QDebug>
#include <QTableWidget>

#include <ITableManager.h>

DraggableHeaderView::DraggableHeaderView(Qt::Orientation orientation, QWidget *parent) :
    QHeaderView(orientation, parent)
{
    m_tag = 0;
    m_tableManager = 0;
    setAcceptDrops(true);
}

void DraggableHeaderView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    if (e->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        int index = logicalIndexAt(e->pos());
        QDrag *drag = new QDrag(this);
        QMimeData *mimeData = new QMimeData;
        //custom drag text with indecies inside
        QString mimeTxt = "MoveHeader;Table:" + QString::number(m_tag) +
                ";Index:" + QString::number(index);
        mimeData->setText(mimeTxt);
        drag->setMimeData(mimeData);
        Qt::DropAction dropAction = drag->exec();
    }
}

int DraggableHeaderView::tag() const
{
    return m_tag;
}

void DraggableHeaderView::setTag(const int tag)
{
    m_tag = tag;
}

void DraggableHeaderView::dragEnterEvent(QDragEnterEvent *event)
{
    if (!m_tableManager)
    {
        event->ignore();
        return;
    }

    QString dragText = event->mimeData()->text();
    int index = dragText.indexOf("MoveHeader;");
    if (index == 0)
    {
        event->accept();
    }
    else
    {
        event->ignore();
    }
}

void DraggableHeaderView::dropEvent(QDropEvent *event)
{
    if (!m_tableManager)
    {
        event->ignore();
        return;
    }

    QStringList dragText = event->mimeData()->text().split(';');
    if (dragText.count() < 3 || dragText.at(0) != "MoveHeader")
    {
        event->ignore();
        return;
    }

    int tableIndex = dragText.at(1).mid(6).toInt();//6 - length 'Table:'
    QTableWidget* tableSrc = m_tableManager->getTableFromIndex(tableIndex);
    if (!tableSrc)
    {
        event->ignore();
        return;
    }

    //dst table as parent for header view
    QTableWidget *tableDst = qobject_cast<QTableWidget*> (this->parentWidget());
    if (!tableDst)
    {
        event->ignore();
        return;
    }

    //move column: modify for your needs
    //now moves only items text
    int columnIndex = logicalIndexAt(event->pos());
    int srcColumnIndex = dragText.at(2).mid(6).toInt(); //6 - length of 'Index:'
    tableDst->insertColumn(columnIndex);
    for (int iRow = 0; iRow < tableDst->rowCount() && iRow < tableSrc->rowCount(); ++iRow)
    {
        if (tableSrc->item(iRow, srcColumnIndex))
        {
            tableDst->setItem(iRow, columnIndex,
                              new QTableWidgetItem(tableSrc->item(iRow, srcColumnIndex)->text()));
        }
        else
        {
            tableDst->setItem(iRow, columnIndex, new QTableWidgetItem());
        }
    }
    tableSrc->removeColumn(srcColumnIndex);
}

void DraggableHeaderView::setTableManager(ITableManager *manager)
{
    m_tableManager = manager;
}
```

Now create custom `QTableWidget` with `DraggableHeaderView` inside

```
class CustomTableWidget : public QTableWidget
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit CustomTableWidget(QWidget *parent = 0);

    void setTag(const int tag);
    void setTableManager(ITableManager* manager);
};

CustomTableWidget::CustomTableWidget(QWidget *parent) :
    QTableWidget(parent)
{
    DraggableHeaderView *headerView = new DraggableHeaderView(Qt::Horizontal, this);

    setHorizontalHeader(headerView);

    setAcceptDrops(true);
}

void CustomTableWidget::setTag(const int tag)
{
    DraggableHeaderView *header = qobject_cast<DraggableHeaderView*> (horizontalHeader());
    if (header)
    {
        header->setTag(tag);
    }
}

void CustomTableWidget::setTableManager(ITableManager *manager)
{
    DraggableHeaderView *header = qobject_cast<DraggableHeaderView*> (horizontalHeader());
    if (header)
    {
        header->setTableManager(manager);
    }
}
```

For converting table index to pointer I use `ITableManager`

```
class ITableManager
{
public:
    virtual QTableWidget* getTableFromIndex(const int index) = 0;
};
```

And implement it in `QMainWindow`

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow, ITableManager
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

    QTableWidget* getTableFromIndex(const int index);
}

QTableWidget * MainWindow::getTableFromIndex(const int index)
{
    switch (index)
    {
    case 1:
        return ui->tableWidget;
    case 2:
        return ui->tableWidget_2;
    default:
        return nullptr;
    }
}
```

Dont forget setup tags (indecies) and table manager for tables (in main window constructor)

```
ui->tableWidget->setTag(1);
ui->tableWidget_2->setTag(2);
ui->tableWidget->setTableManager(this);
ui->tableWidget_2->setTableManager(this);
```

**EDIT:** If you want change custom pixmap for dragging just set `QDrag::setPixmap`

```
void DraggableHeaderView::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *e)
{
    if (e->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        int index = logicalIndexAt(e->pos());
        QDrag *drag = new QDrag(this);
        QMimeData *mimeData = new QMimeData;
        QString mimeTxt = "MoveHeader;Table:" + QString::number(m_tag) +
                ";Index:" + QString::number(index);
        mimeData->setText(mimeTxt);
        drag->setMimeData(mimeData);
        drag->setPixmap(pixmapForDrag(index));
        Qt::DropAction dropAction = drag->exec();
    }
}
```

And method for taking pixmap of column can be like this

```
QPixmap DraggableHeaderView::pixmapForDrag(const int columnIndex) const
{
    QTableWidget *table = qobject_cast<QTableWidget*> (this->parentWidget());
    if (!table)
    {
        return QPixmap();
    }

    //image for first 5 row
    int height = table->horizontalHeader()->height();
    for (int iRow = 0; iRow < 5 && iRow < table->rowCount(); ++iRow)
    {
        height += table->rowHeight(iRow);
    }

    //clip maximum size
    if (height > 200)
    {
        height = 200;
    }

    QRect rect(table->columnViewportPosition(columnIndex) + table->verticalHeader()->width(),
                 table->rowViewportPosition(0),
                 table->columnWidth(columnIndex),
                 height);
    QPixmap pixmap(rect.size());
    table->render(&pixmap, QPoint(), QRegion(rect));
    return pixmap;
}
```

Comment: Thanks!

But how can i see a whole column i'm currently dragging? (as on screenshot on the second table). Now i see cursor only.

Comment: Thanks for great solving my issue!

Comment: Also if its possible, how can i change background of the selected section?

QHeaderView:section:hover does not working.

Comment: @user362316 If you ask for regular changing of selection background then look at `qss` or create another question because it is not relevant for current question. But if  you ask how change background only for drag pixmap then I can suggest you change background before pixmap rendering and restore after.